# Jest SpyOn Method, pass parameter

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

How do I pass a parameter to Jest Spyon Method?
The only parameter is `productId` .

**Requirements:**

```
productId 2 returns true

productId 3 returns false
```

**Method:**

```
jest.spyOn(featureToggles, isEnabled).mockReturnValue(true);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `mockImplementation` instead

```
jest.spyOn(featureToggles, isEnabled).mockImplementation(productId => {
  if (productId === 2) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
})
```